# Moving Glassfish Java EE program to another machine

Tags: jakarta-ee, deployment, glassfish

I am moving a Java EE program that uses Glassfish. I figured out a way to package all the dependencies into a single JAR, but haven't really figured out how to port all the Netbeans JDBC connections with Glassfish. In fact, I don't really know how to replicate the program's integration with Glassfish - It's done by Netbeans.

I've been searching with keywords like "deploying war on another machine" or "moving java ee program to another glassfish server" etc, but to no avail.

Any suggestions would be great!

Edit: I figured the issue out. My project's formatted as an "Application Client" in NetBeans, which appears to mean that it will simply create a JAR that is standalone. When I used the One Jar method to make a self-contained JAR of the program, everything works fine. It appears Glassfish is not even necessary, although it still doesn't deploy the JAR properly when I tried to use Glassfish on it earlier (when I didn't know it doesn't need Glassfish).

A caveat, though, is that persistence.xml is also included in the JAR, which means whenever the project is built, it has to be pointing at the "right" JDBC for production.

Comment: Can't you simply install NetBeans and Glassfish on the new machine, then copy over your project to that machine, re-import it in NetBeans and deploy it?

Comment: Company rule dictates production machine cannot have IDE's installed

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have a basic web application, you can follow the following steps.

First, copy the db connector(s) into the folder `GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/lib`.

Then, copy what you call `dependancies`. These are most probably the DataSource / JNDI / Connection Pool / JMS / Security Realm definitions and settings of your previous installation. You can find them in the domain [configuration](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1753/abhar/index.html) file of your previous GlassFish installation. This file is called domain.xml and is located under `GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1` (supposing that you were using the domain `domain1`). Eventually try to copy the relevant parts of this file, to the new GlassFish path. But I strongly suggest to do the parametrization through the [admin console](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/gilfm.html#scrolltoc).

Restart GlassFish.

If you have packaged your application into a `war` an `ear` or a `jar` package, simply [deploy](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ggjxp.html#ablav) it by means of the `asadmin` `deploy` command (as explained in the linked documentation), or by using the admin console.

Comment: I actually used the solution for this page: http://alexismp.wordpress.com/2008/08/22/im-moving-from-the-netbeans-glassfish-development-server-to-a-production-server-and-my-application-wont-run-help/. However, I can't get my Netbeans to make an EAR or WAR. It kept giving me a JAR in dist/ even though it is an enterprise application that uses EJB. I deployed the JAR through the Glassfish web interface and that didn't do anything (whereas command line call does run the program but without Glassfish)

Comment: Ok, so it's an EJB Module. It should work. Otherwise, post the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Without further details about your project I can't give too many specific steps, however, if this is going into production you really should spend a little time to fix your project so that it builds as self contained a deployment archive as possible. For example, have it use application scoped resources defined in glassfish-resources.xml. Have it bundle all dependent JARs into WEB-INF/lib for a WAR etc.

A previous response mentioned placing your JDBC driver JAR into $GLASSFISH_HOME/glassfish/lib. This might not be the best location depending on your applications requirements and/or the driver.  You should read [Configuring Specifics for JDBC Drivers](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/beamw.html) for instructions on this topic.

It also sounds like you may be new to the JavaEE stack. If you can add more details about the type of project your are building (WAR, or EAR or EJB jar etc) and the current dependencies it has (JARS, resources like JDBC connection pools etc) then I can give you more specific steps.

In the mean time I'd recommend you read the [Glassfish Application Deployment Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2417/index.html) to learn about deploying your application to Glassfish.

Another guide to read the [Administration Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/index.html) and finally to familiarize your self with developing JavaEE6 applications you should look at the application tutorials that are part of the [Glassfish Reference Guides](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/index.html)